# Enable input field on radio button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 radio buttons and 2 input fields. I want to associate a radio button with an input field, so only the selected radio button's input field is enabled and others are disabled.

My html markup is:

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="co" data-for="s" />
    <input type="text" id="s" />
    <br /><br />

    <input type="radio" name="co" data-for="u"/>
    <input type="text" id="u" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

So currently the first radio button is checked, and its input field is enabled. How can I do this with a bit of jquery code?

**EDIT**

I tried this:

```
$("input[type=radio][name=co]").bind({
  change: function () { 
    if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked")
       $("#" + $(this).attr("data-for")).removeAttr("disabled"); 
    else 
       $("#" + $(this).attr("data-for")).attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/DMasH/

```
$("input:radio").on("click", function() {
    $("input:text").attr("disabled", true);

    $(this).next("input").attr("disabled", false)
});
```

Comment: How can this be modified so that you can click the input:text to make it active again instead of the actual radio button for it please (because the visibility of the radio button itself is hidden in my case)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    $("input[type='text']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    if ($(this).next().attr("disabled") == "disabled") $(this).next().removeAttr("disabled");
    else $(this).next().attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Disable all boxes, then enable only the next one.

http://jsfiddle.net/reygonzales/sJZD7/

Answer (score 0):

Solution - http://jsfiddle.net/4uQqE/2/

```
$('input[data-for]').change(function() {
target = $('#'+$(this).data('for'));
$('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    target.removeAttr('disabled');
}});​
```